# I need to get the delta between the date of first payment and user registration date by user

Tags: mysql, sql, date, join, group-by

I have two tables: payments, users.

users:

```
id      regtime
2271    2020-01-17 16:38
```

payments:

```
user_id datetime
2271    2020-03-20 15:11
```

I need to get the date of the first payment for each user from the table `payments` and registrations dates (from the table `users`) of the same users and count a distinction for each of them in days and if it is possible in hours as well.

That means we will get the time in days and hours of user's life on a platform before they make the first payment.

The output should looks like a table with three columns:

```
user_id, full_days_before_first_payment, full_hours_before_first_payment
```

I've already got the first part of a query that returns the list of `user_id` and appropriate first payment date:

```
SELECT user_id, DATE(MIN(datetime)) as First_payment
FROM payments
GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from your existing query, you can just bring the `users` table with a `join`, then do the computation:

```
select 
    u.id as user_id, 
    timestampdiff(day , u.regtime, min(p.datetime)) as full_days_before_first_payment,
    timestampdiff(hour, u.regtime, min(p.datetime)) as full_hours_before_first_payment
from users u
inner join payments p on p.user_id = u.id
group by u.id, u.regtime
```

Comment: Many thanks! And also I need to make an additional filter for table payment like this:
"where payments.site_id=4 AND payments.status=1" 
Where should I put it?

Comment: @AlexSashkovskiy: just add a `where` clause to the query. It goes before the `group by`.

Comment: Already tried, it returns an error:
"Error running query: Unknown column 'payments.site_id' in 'where clause'"

Comment: @AlexSashkovskiy: `payments` is alias `p` in the query, so the `where` clause must be: `where p.site_id=4 AND p.status=1`

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys!

Answer (score 0):

You need to `JOIN` both tables on the user ID column, and user the user's `regtime` and the payment's `MIN(datetime)` for calculations:

```
SELECT
  users.id,
  DATE(MIN(payments.datetime)) AS First_payment,
  DATEDIFF( users.regtime, MIN(payments.datetime) ) AS full_days_before_first_payment,
  TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR, users.regtime, MIN(payments.datetime) )
FROM
  users LEFT JOIN payments ON ( users.id = payments.user_id )
```

Comment: How to add an additional filter for table payment like this: "where payments.site_id=4 AND payments.status=1" Where should I put it?

Comment: @AlexSashkovskiy Add it inside the `ON` conditions: `ON ( users.id = payments.user_id AND  payments.site_id=4 AND payments.status=1 )`

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer helped you, please consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) it and/or [selecting it as the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).